# how to get list of keys and list of value from a single json in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, parsing, mapping

i have a json

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "e_id": 2,
            "e_name": "0",
            "abc": 0,
            "doa": "2021-02-15 13:17:11"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "e_id": 22,
            "e_name": "ok",
            "abc": 1,
            "doa": "2021-02-15 13:17:57"
        }
    ],
    "status": 1,
    "msg": "Successfully fetched"
}
.


How i want two list like 

    List keyList=[
    "id","e_id","e_name","abc","doa"];

and 

    List valueList=[
    {
    2, 2,"0",0,"2021-02-15 13:17:11"
    },
    {
    3, 22,"ok",1,"2021-02-15 13:17:57"
    }
    ];
```

anyOne who can help me??
how to get list of keys and list of value, both are separate lists and fetch only from single json which is given above.

here is my model class---

```
class DataModel {
  List<Result> result;
  int status;
  String msg;

  DataModel({this.result, this.status, this.msg});

  DataModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['result'] != null) {
      result = new List<Result>();
      json['result'].forEach((v) {
        result.add(new Result.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    status = json['status'];
    msg = json['msg'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.result != null) {
      data['result'] = this.result.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    data['status'] = this.status;
    data['msg'] = this.msg;
    return data;
  }
}

class Result {
  int id;
  int eId;
  String eName;
  String abc;
  String doa;

  Result(
      {this.id,
        this.eId,
        this.eName,
        this.abc,
        this.doa});

  Result.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    eId = json['e_id'];
    eName = json['e_name'];
    abc= json['abc'];
    doa = json['doa'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['e_id'] = this.eId;
    data['e_name'] = this.eName;
    data['abc'] = this.abc;
    data['doa'] = this.doa;
    return data;
  }
}
```

i dont need model mapping,
i need only two different list- one is keyList and other one is valuelist form the result.
kindly help me to get this lists

Comment: i have model class but i cant figure out how to fetch those different list

Comment: i just update my question , please check

Comment: Check my updated answer (full answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code which gives you key and values as a List:

You can copy and try it out on dartpad.dev

```
import 'dart:convert';

String json = '''
{
    "result": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "e_id": 2,
            "e_name": "0",
            "abc": 0,
            "doa": "2021-02-15 13:17:11"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "e_id": 22,
            "e_name": "ok",
            "abc": 1,
            "doa": "2021-02-15 13:17:57"
        }
    ],
    "status": 1,
    "msg": "Successfully fetched"
}
''';

void main() {
  Map<String, dynamic> map = jsonDecode(json);
  List<String> keyList = map['result'][0].keys.toList();
  
  List<dynamic> listOfValues = [];
  List<dynamic> valueList = map['result'];
  
  for(int i=0; i < valueList.length; i++) {
    Map<String, dynamic> obj = valueList[i];
    listOfValues.addAll(obj.values);
  }
  
  keyList.forEach(print);
  print('\n\n');
  listOfValues.forEach(print);
}
```

**Output by printing each element of both arrays:**

```
id
e_id
e_name
abc
doa



2
2
0
0
2021-02-15 13:17:11
3
22
ok
1
2021-02-15 13:17:57
```

Comment: result
status
msg
[{id: 2, e_id: 2, e_name: 0, abc: 0, doa: 2021-02-15 13:17:11}, {id: 3, e_id: 22, e_name: ok, abc: 1, doa: 2021-02-15 13:17:57}]
1
Successfully fetched

this is not what im looking for,check my question

Comment: Bro, it's not combined. I have printed it separately.

Answer (score 1):

```
  Map<String, dynamic> json ={
"result": [
{
"id": 2,
"e_id": 2,
"e_name": "0",
"abc": 0,
"doa": "2021-02-15 13:17:11"
},
{
"id": 3,
"e_id": 22,
"e_name": "ok",
"abc": 1,
"doa": "2021-02-15 13:17:57"
}
],
"status": 1,
"msg": "Successfully fetched"
};

  List<String> keyList;
  List<List<dynamic>> valueList = [];
  json["result"].forEach((entry) {
    keyList ??= entry.keys;
    valueList.add(entry.values);
  });
```

Comment: what is 'json' in json['result']??
can you provide me full code like Pratik gave me

Comment: It is the json from your API. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `rootBundle.loadString('assets/json_file.json');`

and then `json.decode(jsonString);`

Now you can use it normally